# Google Sheets: How to calculate accumulated tiered pricing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zx9kZOs7pkQq8LUd6ciAhcqpqe6Xkc6s0pOgMfG8wyU/edit#gid=0

I'm looking to enter `2,097,321` and `Cost:` should have result: `17,207.59`

Basically, the calculation should accumulate the tiered pricing. So it should add `Cost` from column `D` (`3,000`,`2,700`,`2,000`,`1,875`,`7,000`,`6,500`) `= 16,575` and multiply `97,321 * .0065 = 632.59 + 16,575 = 17,207.59`

How would I go about formulating something that would give me this result?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED #2** If you put this formula in H2, it will work. Alternatively you could use a helper column or a helper cell to make it less long.

`=INDEX(E:E,Min(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IF($H$1>B3:B,FALSE,row(B3:B))),B3:B>0))-1)+(H1-INDEX(A:A,Min(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IF($H$1>B3:B,FALSE,row(B3:B))),B3:B>0))))*index(C:C,Min(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IF($H$1>B3:B,FALSE,row(B3:B))),B3:B>0)))`

If you don't mind a helper column, you could use [this file as a solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W66HajKXW8MEJ73XXNGKq3lKnhJT-jlaG6wMTE7hXOc/edit?usp=sharing). Basically just put in an test if it's greater, and then find the minimum row. Use that to create an index to calculate the other columns. I could probably simplify to a single cell with an array formula but I'm tired and this is probably good enough to get you to the finish line.

[image]

**UPDATED**

I was able to strip it down to just a helper cell (J2). That should do it. You could technically replace the formula in I2 with J2's formula but it would be quite long.

Comment: Definitely open to helper columns, will check this method out, thanks for the direction

Comment: Just figured out how to not have helper column